# Is possible to use Metal API for compute simultaneously with OpenGL ES 3.0 for graphics?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal

I would want to port some OpenCL sample using Metal as compute API (as iOS doesn't support ES 3.1 compute shaders still) and OpenGL ES as graphics API, as sample uses OCL/OGL interop seems easiest way to port..
questions is a app can make use of Metal and OpenGL ES APIs simultaneously and if and how interop is achieved i.e. OpenGL mapping a buffer object of data compute by Metal..
thanks..

Comment: You might want to have a look at [MetalGL](https://metalgl.com), which is an implementation of the OpenGL ES API in Metal. In addition to running the OpenGL calls faster than native OpenGL, the next release will support interspersing OpenGL rendering with Metal computer shaders.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use openGL and Metal API simultaneously, but keep in mind, any intercommunication between two layers leads to overhead of host/gpu memory traffic: you have to copy textures and buffers between Metal/OpenGL representations. I think the best way to utilize gpu is use one of these technology stack. Moreover all what you can do with opengl shaders you can do with metal kernels. In general, as i can judge after year of practice with Metal, it is more comfortable and convenient API then OpenGL. Enjoy with Metal, join us:)

Comment: On top of that, there's no hardware-compatibility reason to use GLES 3 instead of Metal on iOS: all iOS devices that support GLES 3 also support Metal.